# Grass raster export to ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, export, grass-7.0

I need to export raster (results of r.walk and r.drain) to ArcMap for comparison.

I did it on data from guatemala - WGS84, UTM16N as r.out.gdal and it works normally.

But when I did this on Slovak data (S-JTSK / Krovak East North, EPSG 5514) and add exported layer into ArcMap, it says:
[image]

I don´t understand, why it´s not working,I set projection at the start.
Any ideas,what to do?
I´m rookie in Grass.

Comment: What if you work in GRASS in WGS84 then once complete, export everything out in WGS84 then reproject results to Krovak in ArcGIS. You may want to CLIP all data to the boundary/extent of Czech and Slovak republics prior to doing any work in GRASS and then again ensure data is in this extent prior to reprojecting since the projection is only meant for use withing the borders of these 2 countries.